# Multiple additions in VHDL using unsigned

Tags: vhdl, simulation, addition, vivado

I am trying to write kind of a strange bit of VHDL that takes in 4 values, and depending on the value of one input will create two averages using several different methods and output the 8 most significant bits of that particular method.

I am using Xilinx Vivado and XSim.

My code worked fine when in an earlier, less complex revision where I was using integers. However, due to the requirements of the project, I have been told I must use std_logic_vectors for my output.

My issue appears when I attempt to do multiple additions in once assignment, and I'm not sure if this is not possible or if I'm just going about it incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity binning_unit is
    port(
        A_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0); -- Imager a pixel data
        B_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0); -- Imager b pixel data
        C_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0); -- Imager c pixel data
        D_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0); -- Imager d pixel data
        MODE    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0); -- Binning unit mode
        LVAL    : in STD_LOGIC; -- Data available for read on ABCD ports
        DATA_AC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := x"00"; -- Binning unit AC output externalized
        DATA_BD : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := x"00" -- Binning unit BD output externalized
    );
end binning_unit;


architecture behavior of binning_unit is

    signal DATA_AC_INT : unsigned (14 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal DATA_BD_INT : unsigned (14 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin 

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     -- Process Description: Creates various simplified outputs via the use of one of several
     --                      data binning techiniques. Values are only available when LVAL is
     --                      high.
     --
     -- Possible values for MODE:
     -- "00" - 2x2 adding mode. Creates 1kx1 pixel output by adding all 4 values per sample
     -- "01" - No adding AB pass-through mode. Simulates 2kx1 pixel output by ignoring CD pixel row
     -- "10" - 1x2 adding mode. Creates 2kx1 pixel output by adding AC and BD values per sample
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    process (A_DATA, B_DATA, C_DATA, D_DATA, MODE, LVAL)
    begin

        if LVAL = '1' then
            case MODE is
                when "00" =>
                    DATA_AC_INT <= (unsigned(A_DATA) + unsigned(B_DATA) + unsigned(C_DATA) + unsigned(D_DATA)); -- Add all four pixels
                    DATA_BD_INT <= (unsigned(A_DATA) + unsigned(B_DATA) + unsigned(C_DATA) + unsigned(D_DATA)); -- Add all four pixels
                when "01" =>
                    DATA_AC_INT <= "00" & unsigned(A_DATA); -- Ignore CD line
                    DATA_BD_INT <= "00" & unsigned(B_DATA); -- Ignore CD line
                when "10" =>
                    DATA_AC_INT <= '0' & (unsigned(A_DATA) + unsigned(C_DATA)); -- Add parallel pixels from both lines
                    DATA_BD_INT <= '0' & (unsigned(B_DATA) + unsigned(D_DATA)); -- Add parallel pixels from both lines
                when others =>
                    DATA_AC_INT <= (others => '0');
                    DATA_BD_INT <= (others => '0');
            end case;
        else
            DATA_AC_INT <= (others => '0');
            DATA_BD_INT <= (others => '0');
        end if;

    end process;

    DATA_AC <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR("00" & DATA_AC_INT(14 downto 9)) when MODE = "00" else -- Use top 6 useful bits shifted right twice (Divide by 4)
               STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(DATA_AC_INT(12 downto 5)) when MODE = "01" else -- Use top 8 useful bits
               STD_LOGIC_VECTOR('0' & DATA_AC_INT(13 downto 7)) when MODE = "10"; -- Use top 7 useful bits shifted right once (Divide by 2)

    DATA_BD <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR("00" & DATA_BD_INT(14 downto 9)) when MODE = "00" else -- Use top 6 useful bits shifted right twice (Divide by 4)
               STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(DATA_BD_INT(12 downto 5)) when MODE = "01" else -- Use top 8 useful bits
               STD_LOGIC_VECTOR('0' & DATA_BD_INT(13 downto 7)) when MODE = "10"; -- Use top 7 useful bits shifted right once (Divide by 2)

end behavior;
```

My testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity binning_unit_test is
begin

end binning_unit_test;


architecture Behavior of binning_unit_test is

    component binning_unit is
        port(
            A_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);   -- Imager a pixel data
            B_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);   -- Imager b pixel data
            C_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);   -- Imager c pixel data
            D_DATA  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);   -- Imager d pixel data
            MODE    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0); -- Binning unit mode
            LVAL    : in STD_LOGIC;                     -- Data available for read ABCD ports
            DATA_AC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); -- Binning unit AC output
            DATA_BD : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0)  -- Binning unit BD output
        );
    end component binning_unit;

    signal A_DATA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal B_DATA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal C_DATA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal D_DATA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal MODE     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := "01";
    signal LVAL     : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal DATA_AC  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal DATA_BD  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

    binning_unit1: component binning_unit
        port map(
            A_DATA  => A_DATA,
            B_DATA  => B_DATA,
            C_DATA  => C_DATA,
            D_DATA  => D_DATA,
            MODE    => MODE,
            LVAL    => LVAL,
            DATA_AC => DATA_AC,
            DATA_BD => DATA_BD
        );

    A_DATA          <= "0000000000001";
    B_DATA          <= "0000000000001";
    C_DATA          <= "0000000001111";
    D_DATA          <= "0000000001111";
--    MODE            <= "00", "01" after 20 NS, "10" after 40 NS,
--                       "11" after 60 NS;
    LVAL            <= '1', '0' after 10 NS, '1' after 20 NS,
                       '0' after 30 NS, '1' after 40 NS,
                       '0' after 50 NS, '1' after 60 NS;

end architecture Behavior;
```

If I use MODE = "00", where it attempts to add all 4 together, the simulation will halt and the error I get is

```
ERROR: Array sizes do not match, left array has 15 elements, right array has 13 elements.
```

The addition of 4 13 bit numbers should be 15 bits, so i'm not sure what the problem is here. Can anyone share some insight on this? Is it not possible to to multiple additions for unsigned? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks

Comment: Word growth doesn't happen automatically : the definitions of the `+` operator all provide a result the same size as the inputs. Now, `("00" & A_DATA) + ("00 & B_DATA) + `... would give you what you want ... but be ugly. Some syntactic sugar such as a resize function may help. But I'd use integers (ranged naturals) everywhere and only convert to the imposed type requirement on output.

Comment: Brian got it right. Moreover, your "10" mode wouldn't work either. I personally prefer to use unsigned then constrained integer as per Brian's suggestion. What I would do is define 4 signals called `X_DATA_U` of type `unsigned(14 downto 0)`, assigned them to `unsigned("00" & X_DATA)` and use that intermediate signal everywhere.

Comment: @JonathanDrolet The 'syntactic sugar' that Brian is referring to is using resize, which I think is much more robust and clearer.  Assume you have your `X_DATA_U` definition.  You would do:  `X_DATA_U <= resize(unsigned(X_DATA), X_DATA_U'length);`.  This way if `X_DATA_U` were to change size, it would ripple automatically without more than a single change to the range of `X_DATA_U`.